# Is there a Python module for transparently working with a file's contents as a buffer?

Tags: python

I'm working on a pure Python file parser for event logs, which may range in size from kilobytes to gigabytes.  Is there a module that abstracts explicit `.open()`/`.seek()`/`.read()`/`.close()` calls into a simple buffer-like object?  You might think of this as the inverse of `StringIO`.  I expect it might look something like:

```
with FileBackedBuffer('/my/favorite/path', 'rb') as buf:
    header = buf[0:0x10]
    footer = buf[0x10000000:]
```

The `mmap` module may fulfill my requirements; however, I have two reservations that I'd appreciate feedback on:

1. It is important that the module handle files larger than available RAM/swap.  I am unsure if `mmap` can do this well.
2. The `mmap` constructors are different depending on OS.  This makes me hesitant as I am looking to write nicely cross-platform code, and would rather not muck in OS specifics. I will if I need to, but this set off a warning that I might be looking in the wrong place.

If `mmap` is the correct module for such as task, how does it handle these two points?  If it is not, what is an appropriate module?

Comment: the differences reflect the underlying system call, giving you the maximum control over how the file is handled on each OS.  the reasonable crossplatform intersection is `mmap(fileno, length, offset=offset)`, with the last param given as keyword; it will do the right thing on all systems with mmap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mmap can easily handle files larger than RAM/swap.  What mmap can't do is handle files larger than the address space, which means that 32bit systems are limited in how large a file they can use.

What happens with `mmap` is that the OS will only have in memory as much data as it it chooses to, but you program will think it is all there.  Be careful in usage patters though since if your data DOESN'T fit in RAM and you jump around too randomly, it will swap (discard pages from your file that you haven't used recently to make room for the new pages to be loaded).

If you don't need to specify anything base `fileno` and `length`, I don't believe you need to worry about the platform specific arguments for `mmap`.  If you do need to worry about the extra arguments, then you will either have to master Windows versus Unix, or pass that on to your users.  I don't know what your library will be, but it may be nice to provide reasonable defaults on both platforms while also allowing the user to tweak the options.  It looks to me that it would be unlikely that you would care about the Windows `tagname` option, also, if you are cross platform, then just accept the Unix default for `prot` since you have no choice on Windows.  That only leaves caring about `MAP_PRIVATE` and `MAP_SHARED`.  The default is `MAP_SHARED`, but I'm not sure if that is the option that most closely matches Windows behavior, but accepting the default is probably fine there.

Comment: Thank you, you've made a strong argument that `mmap` is the way to go, so I'll give it a shot.