# Is there a Python module for transparently working with a file-like object as a buffer?

Tags: python

I'm working on a pure Python parser, where the input data may range in size from kilobytes to gigabytes. Is there a module that wraps a file-like object and abstracts explicit .open()/.seek()/.read()/.close() calls into a simple buffer-like object? You might think of this as the inverse of StringIO. I expect it might look something like:

```
with FileLikeObjectBackedBuffer(urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com")) as buf:
    header = buf[0:0x10]
    footer = buf[-0x10:]
```

Note, I asked a [similar quesetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017349/is-there-a-python-module-for-transparently-working-with-a-files-contents-as-a-b) yesterday, and accepted `mmap`ing a file.  Here, I am specifically looking for a module that wraps a file-like object (for argument's sake, say like what is returned by `urllib`).

*Update*
I've repeatedly come back to this question since I first asked it, and it turns out `urllib` may not have been the best example. Its a bit of a special case since its a streaming interface. `StringIO` and `bz2` expose a more traditional `seek`/`read`/`close` interface, and personally I use these more often. Therefore, I wrote a module that wraps file-like objects as buffers. You can check it out [here](https://gist.github.com/williballenthin/7065476).

Comment: Could you provide more details about the expected semantics of `__getitem__()` method if underlying object doesn't support `.seek()`?   It seems `mmap`ing a temporary file is the simplest solution. You could compare it with `tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile()`-based solution that would implement `__getitem__()` in terms of `.seek()` and depending on the desired semantics either copy the file-like object all at once into `SpooledTemporaryFile` or as need it in `__getitem__()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although `urllib.urlopen` returns a file-like obj, I don't believe it's possible to do what you want without writing your own - it doesn't support `seek` for instance, but does support `next`, `read` etc... And since you're dealing with a forward only stream - you'd have to handle jump-aheads by retrieving until you reach a certain point and caching for any backtracking.

IMHO - you can't efficiently skips part of a network IO stream (if you want the last byte, you still have to get all previous bytes to get there - how you manage that storage is up to you).

I would be tempted to `urlretrieve` (or similar) the file, and `mmap` as per your previous answer.

If your server can accept `ranges` (and the response size is known and from that derived blocks as per your example), then a possible work around is to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving (but can't say I've ever tried that).

Given the example, if you only want the first 16 and last 16 and don't want to do something "too fancy":

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from random import choice
from StringIO import StringIO

buf = ''.join(choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(50))
print buf

sio_buf = StringIO(buf) # make it a bit more like a stream object
first16 = sio_buf.read(16)
print first16

from collections import deque
last16 = deque(iter(lambda: sio_buf.read(1), ''), 16) # read(1) may look bad but it's buffered anyway - so...
print ''.join(last16)
```

Output:

```
gpsgvqsbixtwyakpgefrhntldsjqlmfvyzwjoykhsapcmvjmar
gpsgvqsbixtwyakp
wjoykhsapcmvjmar
```

Comment: This is a good answer, given the example in my question.  I didn't realize the `urllib` object doesn't support `seek()`ing.  Thanks!

Comment: @WilliBallenthin I'm hoping someone has a better suggestion. Short of using `Range` if the server supports it to get your first 16 (a simple `.read(16)` and last 16 bytes using `urllib.urlopen` you have to keep reading the data until you get there...

Comment: @WilliBallenthin also added a bit about using a deque and using that to consume the stream returned - not sure it really helps though...

Comment: Yeah, I'll leave this question open a bit longer to see if anyone else has any ideas.  I'm actually not working with `urllib` at all (it was just an example), but your response encouraged me to think harder about what a "file-like object" really is.  I suppose a better question might be, given `.seek()` and `.read()`, does such a module exist.  I appreciate your answer, though!

Comment: @WilliBallenthin YW - but at this point it may well be worth re-wording the question - and phrasing what you want to achieve from some arbitrary iterable rather than using a specific use-case as you have now - could get more meaningful answers on the case :)